# Checking data in one column in a temp table to a column in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in a temp table, that contains different values for each row. I want to check to make sure the values in that column exist in any row in a different table. If they do not, RaisError is called. I can do this if there is only 1 row in the temp table. However, if there is two or more, I am getting:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
```

My Tsql is:

```
IF ((SELECT tmp.[SomeRefNumber] FROM dbo.TmpTable as tmp) NOT IN (SELECT Source.SameRefDiffTable    FROM SOURCETABLE))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Oh no reference doesn't exist ', 16, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    END
```

I was reading on what is going on, but the solutions I have found seem to be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed my query was bad.. problem solved.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT tmp.[SomeRefNumber] FROM dbo.TmpTable as tmp where tmp.[SomeRefNumber] NOT IN (SELECT SOURCE.SameRefDiffTable FROM SOURCE))
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Oh no reference doesn't exist ', 16, 1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```